# Trying to use a variable for symbolic manipulation for data analysis

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to define a variable as a variable (like in math). the goal of my code is to create Gaussian graphs of many points and create an overall density by adding all these Gaussian distributions. like so:

Note:
data1 is an array of values.

```
def pro1(ee):
    C = np.sqrt(alf)/(np.sqrt(np.pi))
    prof = C*np.exp(-alf*(x - ee)**2)
    prodat1.append(prof)
    return prodat1

for ll in data1:
    pro1(ll)

gauss1 = np.sum(prodat1)
```

My idea is to make prodat1 an array of functions and then have gauss1 be the addition of all these elements.

However, this "x" is undefined and I have no idea how to define it so that x remains an unchanged variable allowing me to take gauss1 as a function and just plot it vs x.

If possible, can anyone tell me how can I use python for symbolic manipulation?

Comment: Have a look at [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html) for symbolic calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Symbolic manipulation is probably overkill. `x` is undefined; why not define it?

```
def pro1(ee, x):
    C = np.sqrt(alf)/(np.sqrt(np.pi))
    prof = C*np.exp(-alf*(x - ee)**2)
    return prof

def gauss1(x):
    prodat1 = []
    for ll in data1:
        prodat1.append(pro1(ll, x))
    return np.sum(prodat1)
```

Comment: Because I need to end up with a function that represents the addition of all the gaussians at the different points gathered from the data. In the end, I just exported the data and used Mathematica's symbolic manipulation. But thank you, and other commenters for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How about constructing lambda expressions and storing those in the list? Then to evaluate the sum at a list of points `x_list`, something like:

```
map (lambda x: sum (map (lambda f: apply (f, [x]), lambda_list)), x_list)
```

where `lambda_list` is the list of lambda expressions.